# Changing configuration on Cisco router

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands

There is a Cisco router configured by another IT guy with specified addresses from ISP, now the problem is that the ISP give us new net mask and default gateway addresses, so what i did was changing the following addresses

old ISP address -

```
ip address: 10.131.61.246

net mask: 255.255.255.252

Default : 10.131.61.245
```

new ISP address -

```
ip address: 10.131.61.246

net mask: 255.255.240.0

Default : 10.131.48.1
```

Old Configuration on router

---

```
flow monitor MellaFMon

 record netflow ipv4 original-input

 exporter MellaFEX

 cache timeout active 5

!

ip source-route

ip cef

!

!

!

ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.50

ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.0 192.168.1.50

ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.50

!

ip dhcp pool 101

 network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0

 default-router 192.168.1.1

 dns-server 192.168.1.4 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2

!

ip dhcp pool WiFi

 network 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0

 default-router 192.168.10.1

 dns-server 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2

!

ip dhcp pool LAN

 network 192.168.40.0 255.255.255.0

 default-router 192.168.40.1

 dns-server 192.168.1.4 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2

!

ip dhcp pool CC-Cam

 network 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0

 default-router 192.168.30.1

 dns-server 8.8.8.8

!

!

!

interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0

 no ip address

 shutdown

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/0

 no ip address

 ip flow ingress

 ip flow egress

 duplex auto

 speed auto

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10

 description Wifi-Vlan-Int

 encapsulation dot1Q 10

 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0

 ip flow monitor MellaFMon input

 ip flow monitor MellaFMon output

 ip nat inside

 ip virtual-reassembly in

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/0.20

 description Server-VLAN-In

 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native

 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0

 ip flow monitor MellaFMon input

 ip flow monitor MellaFMon output

 ip nat inside

 ip virtual-reassembly in

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/0.30

 description CC-Camera-Int

 encapsulation dot1Q 30

 ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0

 ip flow monitor MellaFMon input

 ip flow monitor MellaFMon output

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/0.40

 description LAN-Int

 encapsulation dot1Q 40

 ip address 192.168.40.1 255.255.255.0

 ip flow monitor MellaFMon input

 ip flow monitor MellaFMon output

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/1

 ip address 197.156.90.82 255.255.255.248 secondary

 ip address 10.131.61.246 255.255.255.252

 ip flow monitor MellaFMon input

 ip flow monitor MellaFMon output

 ip flow ingress

 ip flow egress

 ip nat outside

 ip virtual-reassembly in

 duplex auto

 speed auto

!

ip forward-protocol nd

!

no ip http server

ip http authentication local

no ip http secure-server

!

ip nat pool Server 197.156.90.85 197.156.90.85 netmask 255.255.255.248

ip nat pool USER 197.156.90.83 197.156.90.83 netmask 255.255.255.248

ip nat pool server 197.156.90.85 197.156.90.85 netmask 255.255.255.248

ip nat pool CC-Cam 197.156.90.86 197.156.90.86 netmask 255.255.255.248

ip nat inside source list 10 pool USER overload

ip nat inside source static 192.168.1.4 197.156.90.84

ip nat inside source static 192.168.1.3 197.156.90.85

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.131.61.245

!

access-list 10 permit 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255

access-list 10 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255

access-list 20 deny   192.168.1.1

access-list 20 deny   192.168.1.3

access-list 20 deny   192.168.1.4

access-list 20 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255

!

!

!

!
```

new configuration Full

```
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.50
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.0 192.168.1.50
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.50
!
ip dhcp pool 101
 network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.1.1
 dns-server 192.168.1.4 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2
!
ip dhcp pool WiFi
 network 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.10.1
 dns-server 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2
!
ip dhcp pool LAN
 network 192.168.40.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.40.1
 dns-server 192.168.1.4 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2
!
ip dhcp pool CC-Cam
 network 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.30.1
 dns-server 8.8.8.8
!
!
!
!
!
interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 ip flow ingress
 ip flow egress
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
 description Wifi-Vlan-Int
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
 ip flow monitor MellaFMon input
 ip flow monitor MellaFMon output
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.20
 description Server-VLAN-In
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 ip flow monitor MellaFMon input
 ip flow monitor MellaFMon output
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.30
 description CC-Camera-Int
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0
 ip flow monitor MellaFMon input
 ip flow monitor MellaFMon output
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.40
 description LAN-Int
 encapsulation dot1Q 40
 ip address 192.168.40.1 255.255.255.0
 ip flow monitor MellaFMon input
 ip flow monitor MellaFMon output
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 197.156.90.82 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 10.131.61.246 255.255.240.0
 ip flow monitor MellaFMon input
 ip flow monitor MellaFMon output
 ip flow ingress
 ip flow egress
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
ip http authentication local
no ip http secure-server
!
ip nat pool Server 197.156.90.85 197.156.90.85 netmask 255.255.255.248
ip nat pool USER 197.156.90.83 197.156.90.83 netmask 255.255.255.248
ip nat pool server 197.156.90.85 197.156.90.85 netmask 255.255.255.248
ip nat pool CC-Cam 197.156.90.86 197.156.90.86 netmask 255.255.255.248
ip nat inside source list 10 pool USER overload
ip nat inside source static 192.168.1.4 197.156.90.84
ip nat inside source static 192.168.1.3 197.156.90.85
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.131.48.1
!
access-list 10 permit 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 10 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 20 deny   192.168.1.1
access-list 20 deny   192.168.1.3
access-list 20 deny   192.168.1.4
access-list 20 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
!
!
!
!
```

is there anything i have to change on the configuration ? Thanks!

Comment: You have a huge security hole by allowing ip source route.  You should delete it from your config

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your IP route to the specified default gateway from your ISP:

```
IP route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.131.48.1
```

Other than that, your configuration change is correct.

Comment: thanks for your reply sir, i have changed ip route , but still no internet from the router.

Comment: How do you perform the test?

Comment: connect laptop to router, set ip address to obtain automatically.

Comment: What port do you connect your laptop to?

Comment: GE0/0 port of the router.

Comment: What IP address are you assigned then? Port 0/0 has multiple VLANs. Try to ping the ISP gateway from your routers CLI: `ping 10.131.48.1 source 10.131.61.246`. Are you sure your external IP addresses `197.156.90.82 255.255.255.248` have not changed also? Try to ping the internet from your routers CLI: `ping 1.1.1.1 source 197.156.90.82`.

Comment: Please verify you have removed the old ip route also, using: `no ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.131.61.245` in config mode.

Comment: the first two commands reply with Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/2/4 ms but the last: --
ping 1.1.1.1 source 197.156.90.82 is : 
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5). Does these mean they changed my external IP address too?

Comment: Looks like you need to talk to your ISP about those public IP addresses `197.156.90.82 255.255.255.248` if they are still valid or if the subnet/IP addresses have changed also.

Comment: no ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.131.61.245 - no matching route to delete

Comment: Ok, that's good.

Comment: so check with ISP if they have changed public ip addresses? will do that and get back to you sir.

Comment: That would be my approach. Can you add the full configuration with all your changes to your question above?